# Will my passport be considered damaged?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, damaged-passports

My sister drew some marks in pen on my passport page(3). Do I have issues with this passport? Can I get rejections because of this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. To answer we at least need to know which country issued the passport. What type of ‘rejections’ are you referring to? What has your own research on the problem revealed so far?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some countries may consider it damaged, as in this story of Finland rejecting a passport with "unauthorized" stamps made on Azerbaijan border:

https://gorod-812.ru/kak-moy-zagranpasport-stal-nedeystvitelnyim-iz-za-dobryih-inostrannyih-pogranichnikov/

> ...they returned my almost new biometric passport (it is not yet three years old, but it is issued for 10 years) with a note from the Finnish consulate that reads as follows::

> "Please note that your passport is not a valid travel document due to the following defect: "Unofficial stamp on page 45". Your visa application will be submitted to the Visa Department of the Consulate General of Finland at the "Processing temporarily suspended" stage. If you submit a new passport before 18.01, the visa will be issued to you for the already paid consular fee."

> They verbally added that I could, of course, challenge this decision, but warned that it was unlikely that I would succeed.

> I opened this very 45th page in my passport. Two round emblems of the European Games with their symbol in the form of a pomegranate were placed on it next to two ordinary square stamps that are placed on the border.

You would be able to return home with such passport, which would likely include the whole EU area for citizens of EU states, but getting visas / admissions to other countries becomes a gamble.

Comment: -1 I don't see how it's relevant to the OP, in the link you provided the problem was with a Russian passport deemed damaged by the Russian rules. The Finnish consulate was following the Russian MFA guidance. The OP's passport is clearly not Russian.

Comment: (+1) **Souvenir Stamps** are considered a mutilation of a passport. Since 1941 US passports, type VI first issued 1941-02-10, even contain a warning about unauthorized entries: **Alteration or Mutilation of Passport** *Only authorized officials of the United States or of foreign countries may place stamps or make notations or additions to this passport.*

Comment: @MarkJohnson in the story presented, the souvenir stamps were put by authorized officials. As to scribbles - I doubt anyone would care.